# HTML Form Will Not Submit, Likely Form Validation Issues

Tags: html, vba, forms, excel

The following code works just fine when it comes to *completing* the form located on the webpage. The issue arises when it comes time to submit the form.

This appears to be some an issue with validation, as when the form is completed systematically, the submit button is disabled. However, when I go back over the text boxes and manually type in the exact same information, the submit button then becomes available. I believe the form thinks it is incomplete, thus disabling the submit button. I even systematically reenabled this button using `SubmitBtn.disabled = False` (which allows it to be manually or systematically clicked), and it still will not submit.

I have never encountered this type of form validation when filling in webpages.

**I am currently on Internet Explorer 11**

*The following code is complete and can be tested without needing modification. This is a website that is made available to the public*

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub SCRA_Scrub()

    ' #################################################
    ' #### LATE BINDING IS REQUIRED ON ALL OBJECTS ####
    ' #################################################

    Dim IE As Object

    Dim sSSN As String, sLastName As String, sFirstName As String
    sSSN = "123456789"
    sLastName = "DOE"
    sFirstName = "JOHN"

    Set IE = GetIE("scra.dmdc.osd.mil") 'Already Open
    If IE Is Nothing Then
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   'Not open
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate ("https://scra.dmdc.osd.mil/scra/#/single-record")
        End With
    Else    'Reset form
        Dim ClearBtn As Object
        Set ClearBtn = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(0)
    End If
    Sleep 400
    Dim oSSN As Object, oSSN2 As Object, oLastName As Object, oFirstName As Object, SubmitBtn As Object
    Dim oCaptcha As Object
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'For some reason, page shows loaded when it's not. Will loop until obj
    'becomes available
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until Not oSSN Is Nothing And Not oCaptcha Is Nothing
        Set oSSN = IE.document.getElementByID("ssnInput")
        Set oCaptcha = IE.document.getElementByID("recaptcha_response_field")
        DoEvents
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set oSSN2 = IE.document.getElementByID("ssnConfirmationInput")
    Set oLastName = IE.document.getElementByID("lastNameInput")
    Set oFirstName = IE.document.getElementByID("firstNameInput")

    oSSN.InnerText = sSSN
    oSSN2.InnerText = sSSN
    oLastName.InnerText = sLastName
    oFirstName.InnerText = sFirstName
    IE.document.ParentWindow.Scroll 0&, 710&
    oCaptcha.InnerText = InputBox("Security answer (Captcha)")
    'IE.Document.Forms(0).submit
    Set SubmitBtn = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(1)
    SubmitBtn.disabled = False '< The button was disabled, but still doesn't submit
    SubmitBtn.Click

End Sub

Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set RetVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like "*" & sLocation & "*" Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

Comment: Missing **Birth Date** id: `dateOfBirthInput` element?

Comment: It's not required when SSN is entered.

Comment: I coiped your code and only deleted `#If VBA7 Then` and `PtrSafe` since im running on VBA6.5, and it works fine for me. Submit button was grayed out until I typed into the captcha into the prompted inputbox and as soon as i pressed ok, then it submits the form.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. But try removing the line `SubmitBtn.disabled = False`. I just tried this at home PC and I get slightly different results (status bar that acts like it's loading - it's not). After you enter the Captcha with that line removed the submit button would likely still be greyed out. Whatever is causing it is my issue. That line of code is really meant for debugging purposes, I am needing to still find the underlying cause that's preventing the button from being enabled - it's only enabled upon manual entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [some assistance](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1206749-html-form-will-not-submit-likely-form-validation-issues.html), it appears that on this particular form prior to setting the text for each input object that I am required to use `object.setActive`.

So the code would end as follows:

```
oSSN.setActive
oSSN.InnerText = sSSN
oSSN2.setActive
oSSN2.InnerText = sSSN
oLastName.setActive
oLastName.InnerText = sLastName
oFirstName.setActive
oFirstName.InnerText = sFirstName
IE.document.ParentWindow.Scroll 0&, 710&
oCaptcha.setActive
oCaptcha.InnerText = InputBox("Security answer (Captcha)")
```